# Python pp a Json config file

Tags: python, json, pretty-print

i try to Pretty print a JSON file, like i have a login system and the "Data" should get save there.
But if i use

```
          with open('authentication.json', 'w+') as outfile:
              json.dump(data, outfile)
```

It outputs

```
{"username": "censored", "password": "censored"}
```

in the JSON file
But it should Print this in the JSON

```
{
  "username": "censored",
  "password": "censored"
}
```

Comment: have you tried to read the documentation of json.dump() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
    import json
    data = {"username": "censored", "password": "censored"}
    with open('authentication.json', 'w+') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Thanks you! It was that :D i never thought it is so easy!